# Adding a title in godoc

Tags: go, godoc

I am trying to add a title in my godoc. I have referred [godoctricks](https://godoc.org/github.com/fluhus/godoc-tricks#Titles). My godoc looks like below:-

```
// Package hello-world provides a helloworld example
//
// Pre-requisites
//
//  * Go 1.5+
//  * Linux or MacOS
//  * https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/ for executing the tests
//
//
package hello_world
```

But the godoc is showing up as below with Pre-requisites not as title:-

[image]

Can someone let me know what is going wrong?

Environment:-

- Go 1.7
- Mac OSX El Capitan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list seems to cause the problem. You may want to create an issue for that.

If you add any line before listing prerequisites, it will work as expected:

```
// Package hello-world provides a helloworld example
//
// Pre-requisites
//
// You need to have the following:
//  * Go 1.5+
//  * Linux or MacOS
//  * https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/ for executing the tests
//
//
package hello_world
```